# SKNode() only 360deg zRotation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

I am building a game where a playernode can rotate and has to match the angle of a target.
When the target spawns it has an angle between 0 and 359. To match the angles I am working with the zRotation of the player and the target.

My question is, how to tell the player to just rotate from 0 to 359 and not more like 360, 361, 362... and not less than 0 like -1, -2...

I tried to set the players zRotation to 0 if it is larger than 360 and to 360 if it is smaller than 0, but I don't think this is the best way to go.

Anyone has done something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with modulus. Either after your calculation:

`zRotation %= CGFloat(M_PI*2)`

Or on your calculation:

`zRotation = (zRotation + amount) % CGFloat(M_PI*2)`

Comment: `zRotation` is an angle in _radians_. Use `CGFloat(M_PI*2)` instead.

Comment: Thank you guys, it helped me a lot!